# How can I rotate an UIImageView by 20 degrees?

Tags: ios, iphone, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uikit

What do I have to do, if I need to rotate a `UIImageView`? I have a `UIImage` which I want to rotate by 20 degrees.

The Apple docs talk about a transformation matrix, but that sounds difficult. Are there any helpful methods or functions to achieve that?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

A transformation matrix is not incredibly difficult.  It's quite simple, if you use the supplied functions:

```
imgView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(.34906585);
```

(.34906585 is 20 degrees in radians)

---

Swift 5:

```
imgView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: .34906585)
```

Comment: Thanks! And I really thought it's complicated, just because of the "transform matrix" ;)

Answer (score 114):

If you want to turn right, the value must be greater than 0 if you want to rotate to the left indicates the value with the sign "-". For example -20.

```
CGFloat degrees = 20.0f; //the value in degrees
CGFloat radians = degrees * M_PI/180;
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(radians);
```

Swift 4:

```
let degrees: CGFloat = 20.0 //the value in degrees
let radians: CGFloat = degrees * (.pi / 180)
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: radians)
```

Comment: This should be ticked, its the best answer by far!

Comment: Degrees conversion is a really nice plus, this should be the best one!

Comment: Absolutely the best!

Answer (score 10):

**Swift version:**

```
let degrees:CGFloat = 20
myImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * CGFloat(M_PI/180) )
```

Comment: The same code (except let) will work for objective-c too.

Answer (score 5):

**Swift 4.0**

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat(20.0 * Double.pi / 180))
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an extension for Swift 3.

```
extension UIImageView {

    func rotate(degrees:CGFloat){
        self.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: degrees * CGFloat(M_PI/180))
      }  
    }
```

Usage:

```
myImageView.rotate(degrees: 20)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
_YourImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(1.57);
```

where 1.57 is the radian value for 90 degree

Answer (score 1):

This is an easier formatting example (for 20 degrees):

```
CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: ((20.0 * CGFloat(M_PI)) / 180.0))
```

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, using the matrix in `UIAffineTransform` is the only way to achieve a rotation without the help of a third-party framework.