# How to rotate a image (globe) around Y axis?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiimageview, uiimage, catransform3drotate

I have an image of globe which I want to rotate continuously around Y-axis. I also want to simulate it as an 3D rotation. I found some code using CABasicLayer and CALayer, but they rotate an image around Z-axis.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code :

```
CABasicAnimation *rotateAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animation];
rotateAnimation.keyPath = @"transform.rotation.z";
rotateAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:DegreesToRadians(0)];
rotateAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:DegreesToRadians(360)];
rotateAnimation.duration = 10;
rotateAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
// leaves presentation layer in final state; preventing snap-back to original state
rotateAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
rotateAnimation.repeatCount = 99;
rotateAnimation.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];

// add the animation to the selection layer. This causes it to begin animating
[imageView.layer addAnimation:rotateAnimation forKey:@"rotateAnimation"];
```

Comment: Xcode says unexpected @ in program for line no 2 and last line.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But it does not exactly do what I want. I want the image (which is of a globe) to rotate like a real globe. May be I need many images of globe from different angle. But that is not my main concern. Is there any way to rotate like that?

Comment: Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6080043/how-to-rotate-image-360-degrees-endlessly-using-iphone-sdk

Answer (score 0):

I end up using this because I need different views of globes. All images are view of globe taken from different angle. Here there are just 5 images but in actual I'll use around 36 images, because images will have 10 as difference of angle. Thus, 360/10 = 36.

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"globe.png"];
UIImage *image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"globe1.jpeg"];
UIImage *image2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"globe2.jpeg"];
UIImage *image3 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"globe3.jpeg"];
UIImage *image4 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"globe4.jpeg"];

NSArray *imageArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:image, image1, image2, image3, image4, nil];
// set array of images, you want to cycle, to "animationImages" property.
self.imageView.animationImages = imageArray;
//duration of the animation-cycle
self.imageView.animationDuration = 2.0;
// 0 for endless repeation
self.imageView.animationRepeatCount = 0;
//starts the animation
[self.imageView startAnimating];
```