# Rotating UIImageView is not working properly

Tags: iphone

I want to rotate UIImageView and below is my Code.

```
  _imageView1.center = CGPointMake(84, 240);
  _imageView1.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(0.86);
```

But nothing is happen

Comment: Nothing is happening means? is your _imageView1 appears without transform ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use below code :

```
float degrees = 20; //the value in degrees
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degrees * M_PI/180);
```

OR [Check this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/852863/how-can-i-rotate-an-uiimageview-by-20-degrees)