# Swift CGAffineTransform rotation jumps

Tags: ios, swift, rotation, cgaffinetransform

I used the information from [How to rotate an UIImageView using TouchesMoved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25220457/how-to-rotate-an-uiimageview-using-touchesmoved) in my own project. But I found a problem, and I can’t figure out how to solve it.

The view in the original post has the same problem but with the small view it is almost not noticeable. A made this example code. See how the view “jumps”. The touch point is always left of the anchor point. How can I avoid this jump.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var myView: UIView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200))
        myView.center = self.view.center
        myView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(myView)
        myView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.0)

    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let touch: UITouch = touches.first!

        if touch.view === myView {
            let position = touch.location(in: self.view)
            let target = myView.center
            let angle = atan2(target.y-position.y, target.x-position.x)
            myView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: angle)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two major problems:

- You are not taking into account where the original touch was. You need to record that information in `touchesBegan` and work out the angle of your rotation transform with respect to that.
- You are saying `let target = myView.center` as if this were the point we are rotating around. But it isn't, because you moved the `anchorPoint` of `myView`.

Here's working code (taken from my book) that lets you drag to rotate `myView` around its own center:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    var myView: UIView!
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        myView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200))
        myView.center = self.view.center
        myView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        myView.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.view.addSubview(myView)
    }
    func pToA (_ t:UITouch) -> CGFloat {
        let loc = t.location(in: myView)
        let c = myView.convert(myView.center, from:myView.superview!)
        return atan2(loc.y - c.y, loc.x - c.x)
    }
    var initialAngle = CGFloat(0)
    var angle = CGFloat(0)
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.initialAngle = pToA(touches.first!)
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        let ang = pToA(touches.first!) - self.initialAngle
        let absoluteAngle = self.angle + ang
        myView.transform = myView.transform.rotated(by: ang)
        self.angle = absoluteAngle
    }
}
```

But if you really want to rotate around a different point (moving the anchor point as your code does), you'd need to adjust that code accordingly.

Comment: Works like a charm. I was focused on touchesMoved, but forgot touchesBegan. Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your issue is in the line

```
let angle = atan2(target.y-position.y, target.x-position.x)
```

atan2 returns a number between 0 and π, rather than what you want, a number between -π and π.  You should be able to fix it by comparing `(target.y - position.y)` with 0.  When it is greater than zero, your original returned value should be good.  When it is less than zero, you will want to subtract π to get the correct angle.